# App2SD with root?

Tags: app2sd, root-access

So I just rooted my Samsung Galaxy Stellar phone (it's 4.0.2)

I want to be able to move apps to my SD card now, something that has been disabled in 4.0 (at least as the people in the thread [here](http://androidforums.com/android-lounge/682650-app2sd-doesnt-work-my-android.html#post5485444) said)

How do I do this? I have never rooted a phone before so I have literally NO experience with this.

Comment: That's nothing root-specific. Just [search the playstore for "app2sd"](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=app2sd&c=apps) and take a look at the results. If none of those work out (which would make me wonder), an alternative to look at would be [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD).

Comment: App2SD apps don't work for me - It gives an error and won't let me move anything.

Comment: Which App2SD? One of the playstore apps -- or the native one? Did you describe that problem in a question here, including the error messages? Might be solvable. And if App2SD really doesn't work for you, did you take a look at the second option I mentioned (Link2SD)? That's a separate approach, independent from App2SD.